# Adding ... to cell with data till end of line

Tags: excel, vba, custom-cell

I want to add dots(....) to excel cells with data (the dots will come after the data).The dots should fill the space to the end of the line in this cell.
any ideas how can i do it?
Thanks,
Assaf.

Comment: `Cells(i,j).Value = Cells(i,j).Value & "..."` ?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.value & _
                   WorksheetFunction.Rept(".", _
                   Round(ActiveCell.ColumnWidth / 0.53, 0) - Round(Len(ActiveCell) * 2))
```

values will depend on your font size

[image]